# Laravel multiple sortable tables on one page

Tags: php, laravel

Is sorting two or more tables possible in one request?

It is working with just one table but can't figure it out with 2 tables. If I sort by invnum on one table it sorts the other table also.

Table 1

```
<th> @sortablelink('invnum','Invoice', ['parameter' => 'outstanding']) </th>
```

Table 2

```
<th> @sortablelink('invnum','Invoice', ['parameter' => 'past']) </th>
```

The 2 tables have the same heading names and data comes from the same model.

I am using: https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable

Answer (score 1):

> I am author of package in question, please do [see an issue](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable/issues/45). So we can discuss and solve your problem.

As I understand your problem, no it is not possible, to sort two or more tables in one request.